# Linq: Join + Grouping using Lambda Expression

Tags: linq

Is it possible to join two collections and grouping by elements in both collections in lambda expression.

For example:
Collection/Table(1): Student

```
StudentID    StudentName
1                X
2                Y
```

Collection/Table(2):Marks

```
StudentID    Term      Subject      Mark
  1            1       Math         100
  1            1       Physics      90
  1            2       Math         100
  1            2       Physics      100
  2            1       Math         95
  2            1       Physics      85
  2            2       Math         90
  2            2       Physics      100
```

so I need the result collection to contain

```
StudentID     StudentName   Term      Mark
   1              X           1        190
                              2        200
   2              Y           1        180
                              2        190
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show _us_ a simple example. Also, what have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) or [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb341731%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to concatenate two lists.If you want to duplicate values use `Concat` if you don't use `Union`. And then you can use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb534304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to group your result by specific property or key.

You can find numbers of good examples on the Internet or `MSDN`.Just read the documentations of these methods or find some tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Use [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) like:

```
var combinedandordered = foo.Concat(bar).OrderBy(it => it.param);
```

and after this you can use .Join().